# Should I scale actors or actorsystems in AKKA?

Tags: akka, scaling

I have an **EmailValidatorActor** which sends a response to it's Sender about the validity of the email. I have one **ActorSystem** which contains many actors who use this **EmailValidatorActor**.

My question is around scaling the same actor to serve other actors.

If I have to scale the **EmailValidatorActor** to serve more other actors in the same ActorySystem, should I create another **EmailValidatorActor** with the *same address* being used for the previous **EmailValidatorActor**? Can I specify the same name for both the **EmailValidatorActor** to denote they have the same address?

Or should I think in the line of more **ActorSystem**s which contain only one **EmailValidatorActor**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Each Actor must have a unique name (address) in the system. You can use a string interpolation or concatenation for naming it with a suffix. Example: `context.actorOf(YourActor.props(yourParams), "review-" + index)`
- Different ActorSystems are different system (used for isolate scopes and distribute different systems), so for being able to communicate you have to send message outside your ActorSystem. I don't think this is the best solution for you case.
- I would create a [Routing system](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/routing.html)

  - The `Router` is your coordinator Actor for EmailValidatorActors. It's role is to receive requests from other actors and forward them to EmailValidatorActor (`routees`) that will effectively to the job and, eventually, respond to the sender.
  - There are various strategies for dispatch messages to routees (Round Robin, Random Routing, etc.).